# Apache Buildr - extract artifact to project root

Tags: java, apache, buildr, build-tools

I started using Apache builder for a project and I am surprised how little code I need to build my project. But after the first successes, a problem arose:

I have some required text files stored in a jar file which can be downloaded from a repository. I have included it in my buildfile as an artifact and can download an compile with it.

Now I want to extract the contents of the jar and place it in the root folder of my project. Is there a way that Apache Buildr can do this for me? Just adding it to the classpath is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the example you are looking for, from http://buildr.apache.org/artifacts.html

```
bean_jar = file('target/app/bean.jar'=>unzip('target/app'=>app_zip))
```

You can also directly call Buildr's Unzip, just don't forget the `extract` at the end.

```
Unzip.new( 'path/to/extra/to' => 'file/to/unzip').extract
```

Answer (score 0):

A jar file is a zip file. You can use buildr's built-in `unzip` helper to unzip it wherever you'd like. The `unzip` helper is documented in the [artifacts section](http://buildr.apache.org/artifacts.html) of the buildr docs.

If you need to get the filename of an artifact that buildr has downloaded, you can call `#to_s` on the artifact:

```
artifact('net.example:text-files:jar:1.0.0').to_s
```

Comment: I know that I can unzip jars, but how can I specify the path where it shall be extracted?